# Is there a limit to how often we can change our name?

Tags: support, display-names

Is there a limit to how often we can change our names? (i.e In the profile --> recent names)

Or there is no limit? Can we choose names as much as we want?

Comment: @rocket Thanks. I'm mixing French and English here...grr

Comment: @Bart: No problem :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change your name once every thirty days. And only you and moderators can see your recent names.

Comment: yes and there is how much times i can change every thirtydays ? , i mean if no limit ?

Comment: @user998158: no limits are set beyond the rate limit. Every thirty days you can change your name until the end of days, or the end of the site, whatever comes first.

Comment: ok thx , i thought there is max 5 names u can use